# Add column to schema before created_at column

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to add a column to my table.
Here is my migration file:

```
class AddEmail < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :apps, :email, :string, after: :website
  end
end
```

However, when I run it, the newly created email column goes all the way to the last column after updated_at:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141217210326) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "apps", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "iTunes"
    t.string   "website"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "email"
  end

end
```

What I want is for the new email column to go in between the website and created_at column. How do I do that?

Comment: You're using postgresql? Does it actually support explicit column position in `ALTER TABLE` statements? This would seem to imply it doesn't: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Alter_column_position

Comment: ...and the suggested workaround is to add the new col to the end, then add columns after it to copy data into from the cols which should come after, then drop the originals so everything is ordered how you want. That sounds like a _lot_ of trouble.

Comment: Is there a reason why this matters? If so you would have to do a drop and create in the migration to re-order the columns. Other option is to do alter the column order in your `schema.rb` and then run `db:drop db:create db:schema:load`. Note: this will delete all the data in the database. So make sure the order really matters to you because I am unsure why it would.

Comment: The order matters to me because I use Navicat to view the data and with the email field all the way at the end - I can't see it

Comment: Yes - I am using Postgres

Comment: It's not possible in Postgres unless you delete then recreate the columns you want at the end. If the order matters when viewing then just use select statements to order the data. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Alter_column_position#Adding_alter_column_syntax_into_postgres

Answer (score 1):

Postgres doesn't support the ordering of columns in tables.  If you don't have any code in production, just alter the original migration that creates the apps table.